# Reconnectiong to a loopback PSSession from another computer

Tags: powershell, loopback, winrm

On the server , open powershell and type

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
```

A new PSSession is created in the local computer, Get-PSSession returns the session information correctly.

Now go to another computer (client), and open Powershell and type

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName <server> -UseSSL -Port 5986 -Credential (Get-Credential) -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

**Nothing is returned (returns $null)**

I'm 100% positive WinRM is set up properly and the firewall is not blocking access. To verify this:

On the client computer, type

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName <server> -UseSSL -Port 5986 -Credential (Get-Credential) -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

and I can see that the session is created successfully on the server.

And now go to another client computer (client2), and type

```
Get-PSSession -ComputerName <server> -UseSSL -Port 5986 -Credential (Get-Credential) -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

and I see that the session info is returned correctly.

To summarize:

- A PSSession launched into the server, from the server (loopback) is
  not visible to client computers, only visible to the server.
- A PSSession launched into the server, from the client is not visible to
  the server, but it is visible to all client computers.

Why?